# Non-recursive DFS in Java with Iterators

Tags: java, algorithm, iterator, depth-first-search

I want to DFS a graph (non-recursive) using ArrayList and an adjacency list.
I have the following adjacency list

```
2 3 4
1 3 4
1 2 4
1 2 3
```

So node 1 -> 2,3,4  node 2 -> 1,3,4 ...
I already have the adjacency list implemented in arrays like this:
(L are the lines, and l is the elements on the line)

```
    ArrayList<List<Integer>>L=new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer>l=new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I've written on paper the following algorithm to print the DFS of a graph using 2 Stacks. The first node can be any node possible.

```
//all viz[i] = 0;
stack.push(root);
while (!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        node = stack.pop();
        print node;
        viz[node]=1;
        for (each node.childnodes)
              {
              if(viz[i]==0) {stack.push(childnode)}
              }
    }
```

I don't understand how to implement the Iterators so I could use the arraylists with my algorithm.
I'm really grateful for any help!

Comment: You should use an implementation of SortedMap! See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Comment: I have done this in my lib using Guava's `AbstractIterator`, it is probably it bit more complex than you need it. https://github.com/thomasjungblut/tjungblut-graph/blob/master/src/de/jungblut/graph/GraphWalker.java#L67

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use iterators explicitly here - a "foreach" variety of the `for` loop would be sufficient.

Make a [`Stack<Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) to store the index of the current node. Your `for` loop will look like this:

```
Integer node = stack.pop();
// L.get(node) returns List<Integer>, letting you iterate
// over your adjacency list using "foreach" loop:
for (Integer child : L.get(node)) {
    if(!viz[child]) {
        stack.push(child);
    }
}
```

Note that since your "visited" array contains only `1`s and `0`s, you should use `boolean` instead of `int` for its elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't know it could be implemented with foreach. But I don't understand what you mean with Stack<Integer> to store the index of the current node.

Comment: @Stefan I mean Java generic stack collection with `Integer` as its element type.